# How am I able to change this so the substituting works?

Tags: python, text, text-files

The clues file includes 2 letters, and I wish to substitute the second letter in place of the first letter in the text file. It just prints out the text file 3 times with no changes.

This is what is in the clues text file:

> KM
>
> OQ
>
> EG

And this is what is in the text text file:

> g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.

And my code:

```
import string
def convertWords():
    cluesDict = {}
    with open('Clues.txt') as c:
        
        f = open('Clues.txt', 'r')
        clues = f.readlines()
        f = open('Text.txt', 'r')
        text = f.read()
        for z in clues:
            text.maketrans(z[0], z[1])
            print(text)
```

Please can you tell me how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. The first is that `maketrans` creates the translation, but does not execute it. You should change that code to:

```
text.maketrans(z[0], z[1])
print(text.translate(trans))
```

The second problem is that the clues are upper case, while the text is lower case. You can correct that by changing the clues to lower case when you're reading them:

```
clues = [clue.lower() for clue in f.readlines()]
```

Instead, if you want the clues to work both for lower and for upper case, you could do:

```
text.maketrans(z[0].lower() + z[0].higher(), z[1].lower() + z[1].higher())
print(text.translate(trans))
```